# Parse PHP JSON API response

Tags: php, json, api

I have an `API` response that is returning in this format:

```
inventory({
"count": 40, 
"vehicles": [{
"VehicleInfoId": 989889, 
"StockNumber": 787878, 
"make": "ram"
 }]
});
```

I have tried:

```
$final = json_encode($response, true);
```

To try and parse the output with no luck. Any idea of how to approach parsing this response?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well it would be json_decode, but that's only partly JSON.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. JSON requires quotes around object keys. You also can't have a function call around it. It looks more like JSONP.

Comment: @mario The solutions there won't work if the argument isn't valid JSON. They just remove the function call and use `json_decode()`.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, right, the inner part is also JSOL. Gonna add another dupe... / just in case

Comment: @mario thanks that first "Extract JSONP Resultset in PHP" question/answer helped